# Facebook post issue using post api

Tags: facebook, post, charts

I am trying to post images on facebook using graph api and it successfully posted and showing on page but when i see from another facebook account than post is not showing on page and post is posted publicly using api. Is there any solution ?

I am trying to post image using graph api and it successfully posted publicly but not showing on page when i want to see using another account.

Comment: Sounds like your app has not been made "live" yet. As long as an app is in dev mode, all content created via it will only be visible to people with a role in the app.